# podspec flatten directories and imports fail

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I'm using cocoapods 1.2.1

I made this podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "SignalLib"
  s.version      = "2.3.1"
  s.summary      = "Signal Protocol Pod."
  s.description  = <<-DESC
                   This allows an iOS project to retrieve and configure the Signal C implementation
                   https://github.com/WhisperSystems/libsignal-protocol-c
                   DESC

  s.homepage     = "http://www.pangea.com"
  s.license      = { :type => 'GPLv3', :text => <<-LICENSE
                Copyright 2015-2016 Open Whisper Systems
                Licensed under the GPLv3: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
                Additional Permissions For Submission to Apple App Store: Provided that you are otherwise in compliance with the GPLv3 for each covered work you convey (including without limitation making the Corresponding Source available in compliance with Section 6 of the GPLv3), Open Whisper Systems also grants you the additional permission to convey through the Apple App Store non-source executable versions of the Program as incorporated into each applicable covered work as Executable Versions only under the Mozilla Public License version 2.0 (https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/).
                LICENSE
               }
  s.author             = { "XXX" => "XXX@XXX.com" }
  s.osx.deployment_target = '10.9'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/WhisperSystems/libsignal-protocol-c.git", 
                     :tag => 'v' + s.version.to_s}

  s.header_mappings_dir = 'src'
  s.source_files  = ["src/**/*.{h,c}"]
  s.exclude_files = 'src/curve25519/ed25519/main'
  s.public_header_files = ["src/signal_protocol.h", "src/signal_protocol_internal.h", "src/LocalStorageProtocol.pb-c.h", "src/signal_protocol_types.h", "src/curve.h", "src/hkdf.h", "src/ratchet.h", "src/protocol.h", "src/session_state.h", "src/session_record.h", "src/session_pre_key.h", "src/session_builder.h", "src/session_cipher.h", "src/key_helper.h", "src/sender_key.h", "src/sender_key_state.h", "src/sender_key_record.h", "src/group_session_builder.h", "src/group_cipher.h", "src/fingerprint.h"]
  s.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/SignalLib/src $(PODS_ROOT)/SignalLib/src/curve25519 $(PODS_ROOT)/SignalLib/src/curve25519/ed25519', 'CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES' => 'YES' }
  #s.preserve_paths = 'src'

  s.subspec 'protobuf-c' do |ss|
    ss.source_files = 'src/protobuf-c/protobuf-c.h', 'src/protobuf-c'
    ss.public_header_files = 'src/protobuf-c/protobuf-c.h'
    #ss.preserve_paths = 'src/protobuf-c'
    ss.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/SignalLib/src/protobuf-c' }
    #ss.frameworks = 'frameworks'
  end
end
```

This ALMOST works but in some files there is a:

```
#import <protobuf-c/protobuf-c.h>
```

And that fails when Xcode tries to compile it.
The reason is that even if I make a subspec supposed to include the file protobuf-c.h , the file is not in the subspec folder.

I tried using

```
s.header_mappings_dir = 'src'
```

But that also fails. It's actually even worse because the s.public_header_files doesn't even work anymore and only my umbrella header is included as public.

Comment: In the source file, isn't it missing `src/protobuf-c/protobuf-c.c`? or `'src/protobuf-c.*' or something like that?

Comment: nope https://github.com/WhisperSystems/libsignal-protocol-c/blob/master/src/protobuf-c/protobuf-c.c